# sort string of arrays java i.e input="aab cde abc aaa" output="aaa aab abc cde"

Tags: java, string

this doesn't give expected output,Is there any problem in my core logic,any help will be useful to me.

```
       public static String sortedWord(String s){

        String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
        int length = words.length;
        String temp="";


        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
          for(int j=1;j<length-i;j++){
                if(words[j-1].compareTo(words[j])>0)
                       temp = words[j-1];
                       words[j-1] = words[j];
                       words[j] = temp;

            }

        }


            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int k=0;k<length;k++)
            sb.append(words[k]);

             return   sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: What output does it give?

Comment: Show output to better answer...

Comment: So a token gets lost? Investigate that.

Comment: Add the calling statement.Especially s in String s.So that we can work upon token splitting.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot curly brackets around your if block.

You also want curly brackets for your last "for" loop and append a space after appending the word. It's a good practice to always add curly brackets even if there's only one line.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/).  I would do a List and use Comparator, personally.

Comment: In the given case you don't even need a `Comparator` :)